# Dealing with 16 bit characters using sun.misc.Unsafe

Tags: java, memory-management, unsafe

Help me understand something.

Using .. `import sun.misc.Unsafe;`

If i need to put a character `0-127` to some memory address, in order to prevent out of range chars, i do this

```
if (0 != (c & 0xFF80)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Only Ascii characters are supported. 0-127.");
} else {
    // Since Java's chars are 16 bits long, i cast it 
    // to byte (8 bits) and then `putByte()`
    UNSAFE.putByte(address, (byte) c);
}
```

When my test checks what's in that memory

```
    char c1 = Ascii.a;
    asciiEncoder.encode(address, c1);
    assertThat(unsafe.getChar(address), is(c1));
```

This test seems to pass and fail on some machines. **Let me repeat that - this works on some MACs and not the others and some Windows and not the others.**

What is failing? Character different to 'a' is returned.

As i understand it, this is possible if upon allocation, memory is not cleaned up, but does not this take care of this?

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    address = unsafe.allocateMemory(64); // Isn't this mem clean?
}
```

If i change this to 8 bits, test passes always

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    address = unsafe.allocateMemory(8);
}
```

Please help me understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaDoc for `Unsafe#allocationMemory` says:

Allocates a new block of native memory, of the given size in bytes. **The
contents of the memory are uninitialized; they will generally be
garbage**. The resulting native pointer will never be zero, and will be
aligned for all value types.  Dispose of this memory by calling #freeMemory , or resize it with #reallocateMemory .

Which means when you put `byte` there and read `char` back you get extra byte of garbage.

Comment: It pays to RTFM. Thanks hoaz! Thanks a lot!